# Which Buddhist traditions have no gender divisions at all

Tags: gender

I had a conversation with a friend and she was very upset that there were some gender division in the group I practice with. We have some single sex retreats and some study groups are single sexed. But mostly things are mixed.

If my friend wanted to practice Buddhism with a group with no gender divisions whatsoever - what group would that be? So all study, retreats, events would be mixed and if there is a monastic community then that would be mixed too.

Comment: Even the bathroom are sprites for the security reason. We sprit sex for the security reason. She may say she can takecare herself, but have she ever taken care of how hard the male control his mind when he being with a woman?  **We meditate for taking care each other**, not for feminists or meninist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you asking about a tradition or a community? If the latter, there are many. Most of the "insight meditation" communities, e.g. IRC, Spirit Rock, IMS etc  in the US are sex- unsegregated. But if you ask about the Theravada tradition that these communities trace their lineage to, usually in the original country (MMY, SLK, THA etc), there **is** a separation in the seating in the meditation hall.

However, there are many religious activities that are not segregated - families often do them together - e.g., food donation and other donation at monasteries, meeting monks for advice or to pay respects and volunteer work of various sorts.

Answer (score 4):

Our branch of Rinzai Zen has no gender division other than that we segregate by sex when bunking up for sesshin.  I can’t think of too many Buddhist communities in the US that would even consider that, quite frankly.  I think the group you’re with would be the exception in the West, at least.